# Use new fingerprint API from Android for multiple users

Tags: fingerprint, android-6.0-marshmallow

We are creating a timestamp application on Android and ideally this would use fingerprint to identify the user.

In one organisation there can be like 150 different users.  Would the fingerprint API allow multiple users?  Or is this currently only for the owner of the device?  If this is only for the current users, are there any other API's available that would allow this?  If not I think we need to abandon this road completely.

Comment: Have you found a solution to identify multiple users without using any external device? @rept

Comment: @AlejandroMartínezMartínez unfortunately not. Pretty certain it's not possible with the current API's.

Comment: You can use Samsung Pass SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android M or Samsung or iPhone APIs only allow to verify current user against user of device.

There's some fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. These SDKs allow to get fingerprint image or template. Scanners are plugged on USB port so you can't charge tablet and use fingerprint scanner simultaneous. For instance:

- https://www.dermalog.com/products/hardware/fingerprint-scanners
- https://www.futronic-tech.com/pro-detail.php?pro_id=1543
- https://www.hidglobal.com/products/embedded-modules/single-finger-modules

There's also some devices with integrated fingerprint scanner and with SDK to get fingerprint image or template.

Comment: Hi @LaurentY, not what I hoped to hear, but very useful thanks!  I'll keep an eye open to find API's that can do multi-user and connect to a fingerprint device.

Comment: Two out of three links are not functional at the moment will you please share some relatable data.

Comment: I fixed  dead links :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use android.hardware.fingerprint.Fingerprint.class

```
/**
* Container for fingerprint metadata.
* @hide
*/
public final class Fingerprint implements Parcelable {
    private CharSequence mName;
    private int mGroupId;
    private int mFingerId;
    private long mDeviceId; // physical device this is associated with
 ...
}
```

to compare against with enrolled one together with FingerprintManager inner class but visibility of api is hidden and you need use reflections

```
 /**
 * Container for callback data from {@link FingerprintManager#authenticate(CryptoObject,
 *     CancellationSignal, int, AuthenticationCallback, Handler)}.
 */
public static class AuthenticationResult {
    private Fingerprint mFingerprint;
...
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate in brief.

Comment: @Kels do you know how use reflections ? if so  just grab mFingerprint  field while fingerprint is rolled , save (its properties) file db or whatsoever (associate fingerprint id with your user ) and compare against one when authenticated. If you don't know learn basics then u will understand what i wrote.