# Multiple Fingerprint accounts in android phone

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

My question might be silly. But I would like to create `multiple accounts`(50 to 100 accounts) in fingerprint embedded android device. Cos I want to use those for authentication in my application.

As I know, almost of the fingerprint embedded phone have `limitation` for account number. For example, `Samsung Note(4)` limits up to `three` finger scanner accounts.

Is there any way to create multiple accounts in `rooted android device`?

Is there any other `android custom ROM` to solve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124499/use-new-fingerprint-api-from-android-for-multiple-users

Comment: So I have no chance to resolve even android device is rooted.?