# Cordova: scan fingerprint and save it

Tags: android, cordova, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I would like to build an app that scans user's fingerprint (using android's fingerprint scanner that unlocks the phone) and save it.

Till now, I've found only fingerprint auth plugins for Cordova, but it is not what I'm looking for.

Also, I have doubts if I want to save scanned fingerprint as a image, or there's maybe a standard for such storage? (maybe some X/Y data etc.?)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use new fingerprint API from Android for multiple users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124499/use-new-fingerprint-api-from-android-for-multiple-users)

Comment: No not possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124499/use-new-fingerprint-api-from-android-for-multiple-users/33142306#33142306