# Can I get the fingerprint image scanned by my device's fingerprint scanner?

Tags: java, android, sha1, fingerprint, android-keystore

I am deeply stuck while developing an application which requires the following functionality:

1. I should be able to ask the user to scan their fingerprint through the scanner provided by my android device.
2. The scanned fingerprint should show up to the user in the form of an image, that his fingerprint impression looks like this.

How will I be able to achieve this? And if not show the user the image, can I store it as a template? Or is there any other way around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124499/use-new-fingerprint-api-from-android-for-multiple-users
I doubt this is possible

Comment: "How will I be able to achieve this?" -- you will not be able to achieve it, if your objective is to use some fingerprint scanner built into the device. "And if not show the user the image, can I store it as a template?" -- no. "Or is there any other way around?" -- as the duplicate answer indicates, you might be able to use some sort of external scanner (USB, Bluetooth, etc.), if they have an SDK for Android that meets your needs.